# sqlalchemy IS NOT NULL select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I add the filter as in SQL to select values that are NOT NULL from a certain column ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL;
```

How can I do the same with SQLAlchemy filters?

```
select = select(table).select_from(table).where(all_filters)
```

Comment: What is `all_filters` here? Why the `select_from`?

Comment: And do you have a table definition or do you need to use column literals?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

`column_obj != None` will produce a [`IS NOT NULL` constraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.__ne__):

> In a column context, produces the clause `a != b`. If the target is `None`, produces a `IS NOT NULL`.

or use [`is_not()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.is_not)<sup>*</sup>:

> Implement the `IS NOT` operator.
>
> Normally, `IS NOT` is generated automatically when comparing to a value of `None`, which resolves to `NULL`. However, explicit usage of `IS NOT` may be desirable if comparing to boolean values on certain platforms.

Demo:

```py
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import column
>>> column('YourColumn') != None
<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x10f81aa90>
>>> print(column('YourColumn') != None)
"YourColumn" IS NOT NULL
>>> column('YourColumn').is_not(None)
<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x11081edf0>
>>> print(column('YourColumn').is_not(None))
"YourColumn" IS NOT NULL
```

You can't use `is not None` here, because the [`is not` object identity inequality test](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) can't be overloaded the way `!=` can; you'll just get `True` instead as a `ColumnClause` instance is not the same object as the `None` singleton:

```
>>> column('YourColumn') is not None
True
```

---

<sup>*)</sup> The method was formerly named `isnot()` and was renamed in SQLAlchemy 1.4. The old name is still available for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 160):

Starting in version 0.7.9 you can use the filter operator `.isnot` instead of comparing constraints, like this:

`query.filter(User.name.isnot(None))`

This method is only necessary if pep8 is a concern.

source: [sqlalchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.isnot)

Comment: Beyond making pep8 happy, I think this is a better solution because `NULL` is not a valid as the RHS of `!=` in SQL and using `isnot` better conveys your intentions for what you want the generated statement to look like.

Comment: @Josh: SQLAlchemy won't emit `!= NULL` however, even if you use `column != None` on the Python side; you get `IS NOT NULL`. Using `.isnot()` lets you *force* `IS NOT` on other types however (think `.isnot(True)` against boolean columns, for example).

Answer (score 70):

In case anyone else is wondering, you can use `is_` to generate `foo IS NULL`:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import column
>>> print(column('foo').is_(None))
foo IS NULL
>>> print(column('foo').isnot(None))
foo IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for but Google sent me here!