# Elegant way to filter by none or not none

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The following SQLAlchemy code works, but looks un-pythonic:

```
if has_died: # has_died: True or False
  query = query.filter(User.died_at != None)
else:
  query = query.filter(User.died_at == None)
```

What is a more elegant way to add the filter?

Comment: boolean. True or False

Comment: I think it's mainly ugly that I have to rewrite the whole line just for a simple change from != to == ...

Comment: Not as ugly as using the ternary operator.

Comment: I don't know SQLAlchemy, but I assume there's some magic going on there that's returning something other than `True` or `False` for the comparisons.

Comment: Yes, it is. This [magic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21784915/1377864). I don't think it's possible to do it any better.

Comment: Repeated code is a _sign_ that you should _make sure_ that you can't do it better. But sometimes it would take more/uglier code just to not have any repetition.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could do this:

```
query = query.filter((User.died_at != None) if has_died else (User.died_at == None))
```

But it's a bit hard to read. I think how you're doing it is fine.

Comment: @Tobo, I agree, which is why I think you should stick with what you have :).

Answer (score 3):

You could rewrite it as one line with a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html?highlight=ternary#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator)

```
query = query.filter((User.died_at != None) if has_died else (User.died_at == None))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

`query = query.filter(bool(User.died_at) == has_died)`

It returns:

- `False` if `User.died_at` is `None` and `has_died` is `True`
- `True` if `User.died_at` is `None` and `has_died` is `False`
- `True` if `User.died_at` is not `None` and `has_died` is `True`
- `False` if `User.died_at` is not `None` and `has_died` is `False`

Which is the intended behavior...

But then again, not sure if it is easier to understand than your piece of code!

Comment: `User.died_at != None` and `User.died_at == None` don't return a `bool`; they return a SQLAlchemy object. As linked by [Yaroslav Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377864/yaroslav-admin) in the question comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784851/sqlalchemy-is-not-null-select/21784915#21784915

Comment: Oh I am not familiar with SQLAlchemy syntax. Stricly speaking in python, a `None` is considered as `False`. Is there a way to make this call valid ? Because then I think it is the most elegant way to do it. Otherwise sorry for my faulty contribution.

Comment: No problem. Even if it behaved closer to how you expected, while `bool(None) == False`, `None != False`, so they're not the same thing. You could have a value that could be `True`, `False`, or `None`, with each one having it's own meaning. For example, if it's the answer to a yes/no question, they might mean `Yes`, `No`, and `Unanswered`.

Comment: Indeed, my comment could be misleading, it is `bool(None)` that is considered as `False`. It is true that `None`, `False` and `True` all have different meanings.